# Can all applications be decompiled?

Tags: decompiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What types of executables can be decompiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672/what-types-of-executables-can-be-decompiled)

It's pretty popular to decompile the Minecraft classes to edit and add your own mods. Is every Java application decompilable? Does it stop at Java applications?

I'm a little concerned about this, but no one else seems to be so maybe I just don't understand. What's stopping people decompiling *Microsoft Word* and making their own custom changes? Or decompiling *World of Warcraft* and stealing interesting bits of their code?

Comment: Every application must be executed -- *read and understood* -- by something. Therefore, every application can be "decompiled". However, this in no way implies that "decompiling" will lead to any kind of *sane* source code, or even a full reconstruction. (In the case of a Java application it is rather easy to *stub in your own classes* if the signature matches and they are loaded by the classloader instead of the original classes.)

Comment: Quick answer is it's easier to replicate the behavior of an existing app rather than decompiling and using another person's code. You ever tried following a perl script written by some admin who had an enthusiasm for regexp patterns?

Comment: Related (not exactly the same): [What types of executables can be decompiled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672/what-types-of-executables-can-be-decompiled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte code (as java and c# get compiled into) can easily be decompiled. There are ways around it as in obfuscation and other alternatives. C and C++ get compiled into native machine code, and is difficult to "decompile". But someone with the correct skillset could be able to reverse engineer it anyway.

Edit: Note that obfuscation will not make it harder to decompile the byte code - it will be just as easy, but the code will be harder to make any sense of.